# Visual Indicator For Manually Created Documents vs. Automatically Generated Documents

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, design, visual-design, human-interface-guideline

I'm working on a UI that is a master-detail-detail view that displays a list of documents to a user.  Some documents are manually created and other documents are automatically generated.

I have a requirement to add a visual indicator that differentiates between a manually created document and an automatically generated document.  The visual indicator would be placed somewhere somewhere in the row of each document in the list of documents.

Are there any universal indicators or icons that would accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us more about the autogenerated items? Are they placeholders, or are they some kind of summary of other users' work?

Comment: The words manual or automatic.

Comment: You could give the auto-generated documents a title that reflects this. For example: **Document 3 scheduled report**, or **Document 3 generated report**, or **Document 3 automated report**, or whatever terms work for your users and your business.

Answer (score 3):

You could user a "[user](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/user/)" icon for a manually generated document, and a "[computer](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/desktop/)" icon for the automatically generated ones.